# serilog convert scalarvalue into a dictionary inside a sink

Tags: c#, serilog, marten

Can i convert this scalarvalue into two separate properties inside a sink?

The sink will store the logevent as a json object inside Postgresql using Marten.

```
var sensorInput = new { Latitude = 25, Longitude = 134 };
Log.Information("Test {sensorInput}", sensorInput);
```

In my json object i want store this as two seperate properties
so i can filter on one of the properties

The JsonFormatter is also not converting this object into two separate properties. I want to store the separate property so i can query on those properties

see https://github.com/mdissel/serilog-sinks-marten/blob/master/src/Serilog.Sinks.Marten/LogMessage.cs

Comment: In the example on the Homepage of Serilog you will see that a reference parameter to the Information call is prefixed with the @ character

Comment: Thansk @Steve but it's not the rendering, but in the sink.. i updated my question a bit

Comment: Howdy! The `@` doesn't control rendering, it controls the capturing process, so without it here I think all you'll get is a string representation of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed! Use the @ in the message to convert the properties into a Dictionary.